# Getting error during adding a comment as notnull

Tags: python, django, notnull

I don't understand why I am getting this one I tried making null=True, blank=True but still, it does not solve my error, at last, I thought of sending it here ...!!  please tell me where I am going wrong

**Models.py**

```
class Certification(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, 
            unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course_image = models.ImageField()
    course_taken = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mentor_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    #body = RichTextField()
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

class Comment(models.Model):
    certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certification, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__' 
    exclude = ['certificate']
    
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm',})
    
    self.fields['body'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm',})
```

**Views.py**

```
def certificatePage(request,pk):
    certi = Certification.objects.get(id=pk)
    count = certi.comment_set.count()
    comments = certi.comment_set.all()
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.certi = certi
            comment.save()
            
    context = {
    "certi": certi,
    'count':count,
    'comments':comments,
    'form':form
    }
    return render (request, 'base/certificate.html',context)
```

[Click On The Image To See The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k50d.png)

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: I got it where i am going wrong its in the views.py it should be comment.certificate = certi .. instead of comment.certi = certi